# Where are the exceptions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Where in the dashboard can the exceptions be found?

I'm quite certain that I send a proper exception message because I get 200 response.
I set it up following [this api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#exDescription).

[image: This is how my dashboard looks now. Exceptions anywhere?]

P.S. This is a WEB App.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need to set up a custom report to see the exceptions (exception description is a dimension in custom reports afaik they show up nowhere else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [exceptionDescription](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=exceptions&jump=ga_exceptiondescription) dimension is not available via the Real-time reports.  It is only available from the standard reports.  It can take up to 24 hours before this data will be displayed on the standard reports.

You can probably add it as a secondary dimension to most of the Standard Reports I haven't checked.  I know you can add it to a Private dashboard widget.

Comment: Give me 24 hours to mark this as the answer. :} In meantime, you can help me generate that custom exceptions report. (didn't believe that GA can be tricky stuff)

Comment: One other idea is.. if i can't get realtime exceptions reports, should  I maybe simply fire a custom events categorising them as exceptions..?